# Oracle pl/sql Procedure to update table - exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

This is my first query on PL/SQL and I did spend an hour trying to find answers on the net, anyway - here it goes.

I'm writing a procedure to update a table and it all works fine, however when I typed in to update a `job_id` that doesn't exist, I expected my exception handling to tell me that the `job_id` is invalid, however I got no error message.

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_JOB(p_job_id jobs.job_id%TYPE, p_jobnew jobs.job_title%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE JOBS SET job_title =p_jobnew WHERE JOB_ID = p_job_id;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No rows have been updated');
END;
/
```

I then tried to update a job_id that I knew didn't exist to see if the exception works by typing the following

```
EXECUTE UPD_JOB('ABCXXX','WILL FAIL');
```

Answer (score 6):

From ["Handling PL/SQL Errors"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm#725):

> `NO_DATA_FOUND`
>
> A SELECT INTO statement returns no rows, or your program references a deleted element in a nested table or an uninitialized element in an index-by table. SQL aggregate functions such as AVG and SUM always return a value or a null. So, a SELECT INTO statement that calls an aggregate function never raises NO_DATA_FOUND. The FETCH statement is expected to return no rows eventually, so when that happens, no exception is raised.

You're not using a statement that would cause a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception to be raised.

Maybe you can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. From ["Performing SQL Operations from PL/SQL"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm):

> To find out how many rows are affected by DML statements, you can check the value of `SQL%ROWCOUNT`...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_JOB (p_job_id jobs.job_id%TYPE,
                                     p_jobnew jobs.job_title%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE JOBS
         SET job_title = p_jobnew
         WHERE JOB_ID = p_job_id;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No rows have been updated');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought I needed to use an exception to produce an error message but the IF SQL%ROWCOUNT=0 solution works perfectly.